# How to launch app on click of url in browser Android

Tags: android, android-activity, google-play

i have to open(launch)app on click of url  from browser if app is installed on device .

if app not installed than it should redirect to google play store.

eg.url  - http://testurl.com/event?event_code=u322

i am using this code

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.quantumsolutions.activities.Splashscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="GiftFund.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="giftfund.com/details?id=123"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="giftfund.com/event?event_code=PF38A"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="qa.GiftFund.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="dev.GiftFund.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="giftfund.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="qa.giftfund.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="dev.giftfund.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!--
             <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="giftfund" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        -->

    </activity>
```

user can receive this url by mail,or post on facebook or text message but currently if i get url by gmail than click on url able to launch app  but in browser or text message when i click on this url

for example from basecamp or facebook post open in browse it does not showing me
my app in pop up and re directs me to play store and showing install app but app is already installed.

Comment: unable to understand you are you trying to achieve. Rephrase your sentences please.

Answer (score 4):

You have to make your own `<intent filter>` scheme, but the order of the `intent filter` elements are important:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="my_app" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

If the link will start with `my_app:` your app will launch.

**EDIT:**

Set your scheme for example to `my_app` and modify your link to `my_app://yourlink.com/something` Get rid of `http`. Also try to set in your activity this: `android:exported="true"`

Comment: what should write in scheme ="testurl.com" ?

Comment: in your case try to add scheme = "http"

Comment: can you update your question with your AndroidManifest file? I don't know whats wrong with my code, it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want launch your app, that already installed on user device, you can use method with custom scheme from **zkminusck** answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32026047/2717821

But it not possible redirect to google play if app doesn't installed